# How can I use the official jenkins image based on alpine in my dockerfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, alpine-linux

As it is shown in the [readme](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/) of the official docker image, exists a prebuild image for LTS or weekly release. I can use it easily adding the `FROM jenkins/jenkins` directive in my docker file, as usual. In the documentation, is commented that you can also use the alpine based image.

If you see the [github code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker), here we have several Dockerfile. One of them is the Dockerfile-alpine file. But I cannot find it in dockerhub

Does exists a prebuild image of Jenkins using alpine or do I need to download the code an compile myself? If exists, which tags are needed for using -as example- jenkins + lts + alpine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**jenkinsci/jenkins:alpine**
or
**jenkinsci/jenkins:lts-alpine**

All official tag list=> https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/jenkins/tags/

Comment: Add more description to your answer. once the link is revoked in future, it should not make your answer useless.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I do not know how I can miss this page.

Answer (score 0):

On dockerhub the various images versions for a software, are separated by a tag that is used to label the different images.

On dockerhub, you can find the tags tabs which documents all the different flavors for an image.

In particular for [jenkins](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/jenkins/tags/) you can find the `jenkinsci/jenkins:alpine` and `jenkinsci/jenkins:lts-alpine` images. Thus the images are already on dockerhub and you don't need to build them yourself.